# Django url pattern matching

Tags: python, regex, django

I've been over this for too many hours now and I cannot see anymore what I'm doing wrong:

```
url(r'^baz/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/[0-9]/$', 'foobar.views.baz')

def baz(request, xxx, yyy, zzz):
    pass
```

And this is the actual URL being requested:

```
http://localhost:8000/baz/75ca0f5bf13d67895e23419c25f82e87f3f5f95f/f733dbf686cd51f911e533d5a351f81394c9db5c/0/
```

Django keeps throwing this error at me:

```
baz() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You're missing the last block of parens in your regular expression.

```
url(r'^baz/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/([0-9])/$', 'foobar.views.baz')
```

With the parens Python will capture the `[0-9]` as a group and now you'll get all 3 parameters (+ the `self`) instead of 2.

Comment: Thanks Matthias! I actually had the parens in some earlier rev of that file!